# How to initiate USB bulk transfers in usb-vhci

Tags: linux, usb, libusb

**EDIT: reformulating this question as I've managed to get the basics to work, but still experience problems.**

I'm trying to emulate a USB device (bar code scanner) for testing purposes using [usb-vhci](https://sourceforge.net/projects/usb-vhci/), and I'm having some problems.

To give some context: the device is a CDC abstract modem, and the client - a java program - communicates with it over the serial line using AT commands.

Basically, I've got my device up and running, it registers itself correctly and I'm able to receive commands from and respond to the client.

The main problem appears to be that as soon as the device starts up or receives a bulk transfer from the host it triggers an ongoing stream of bulk  and interrupt IN transfers (massive amounts, my usbmon log grows to 100 MB in a few seconds).

First at startup, where it keeps spewing out (mainly)  bulk IN transfers until I receive the SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE request and then they stop. Then, when the client sends the commands (AT command via the serial device) it starts again.

I'm guessing this is because I'm not responding correctly to some transfer, but I can't figure out what it is.

I've been comparing the usbmon output of my device with that of the real device, but so far I haven't been able to detect any difference that would explain why my emulated device behaves like this and the real one doesn't.

I basically started out with the example code found in libusb_vhci/examples/virtual_device2.c and adapted it to mimic the actual device. First off the device descriptors:

```
const uint8_t dev_desc[] = {
/* Device Descriptor */
0x12,       //bLength           18
0x01,       //bDescriptorType       1
0x00, 0x02, //bcdUSB            2.00
0x02,       //bDeviceClass          2 Communications
0x00,       //bDeviceSubClass       0
0x00,       //bDeviceProtocol       0
0x40,       //bMaxPacketSize0       64
0x5a, 0x06, //idVendor          065a
0x02, 0xa0, //idProduct         a002
0x00, 0x01, //bcdDevice         1.00
0x00,       //iManufacturer         0
0x01,       //iProduct          1
0x00,       //iSerial           0
0x01        //bNumConfigurations        1
};

const uint8_t conf_desc[] = {
/* Configuration Descriptor */
0x09,       //bLength           9
0x02,       //bDescriptorType       2
0x43, 0x00, //wTotalLength          67 ??
0x02,       //bNumInterfaces        2
0x01,       //bConfigurationValue       1
0x00,       //iConfiguration        0
0x80,       //bmAttributes (Bus Powered)    0x80
250,        //MaxPower          500mA

/* Interface Descriptor 0 */
0x09,       //bLength           9
0x04,       //bDescriptorType       4
0x00,       //bInterfaceNumber      0
0x00,       //bAlternateSetting     0
0x01,       //bNumEndpoints         1
0x02,       //bInterfaceClass       2 Communications
0x02,       //bInterfaceSubClass        2 Abstract (modem)
0x00,       //bInterfaceProtocol        0 None
0x00,       //iInterface            0
/* CDC Header */
0x05,       //bLength           7
0x24,       //bDescriptorType       5
0x00,       //bEndpointAddress      0x01 EP 1 OUT
0x10,       //bcdCDC            1.10
0x01,       //"
/* CDC Call Management */
0x05,       //bLength           3
0x24,       //CDC_CS_INTERFACE
0x01,       //CDC_CALL_MANAGEMENT
0x01,       //bmCapabilities        0x01
0x00,       //bDataInterface        0
    /* CDC ACM */
0x04,       //bLength           2
0x24,       //CDC_CS_INTERFACE
0x02,       //CDC_ABSTRACT_CONTROL_MANAGEMENT
0x02,       //bmCapabilities        0x02
/* CDC Union */
0x05,       //bLength           3
0x24,       //CDC_CS_INTERFACE
0x06,       //CDC_UNION
0x00,       //bMasterInterface      0
0x01,       //bSlaveInterface       1
/* Endpoint Descriptor */
0x07,       //bLength           7
0x05,       //bDescriptorType       5
0x83,       //bEndpointAddress      0x83 EP 3 IN
0x03,       //bmAttributes          3
0x40, 0x00, //wMaxPacketSize        0x0040 1x 64 bytes
0x0a,       //bInterval         10      
/* Interface Descriptor 1 */
0x09,       //bLength           9
0x04,       //bDescriptorType       4
0x01,       //bInterfaceNumber      1
0x00,       //bAlternateSetting     0
0x02,       //bNumEndpoints         2
0x0a,       //bInterfaceClass       10 CDC Data
0x00,       //bInterfaceSubClass        0
0x00,       //bInterfaceProtocol        0
0x00,       //iInterface            0
/* Endpoint Descriptor */
0x07,       //bLength           7
0x05,       //bDescriptorType       5
0x01,       //bEndpointAddress      0x01 EP 1 OUT
0x02,       //bmAttributes          2
0x40, 0x00, //wMaxPacketSize        0x0040 1x 64 bytes
0x00,       //bInterval         0
/* Endpoint Descriptor */
0x07,       //bLength           7
0x05,       //bDescriptorType       5
0x82,       //bEndpointAddress      0x82 EP 2 IN
0x02,       //bmAttributes          2
0x40,0x00,  //wMaxPacketSize        0x0040 1x 64 bytes
0x00        //bInterval         0
};

const uint8_t str0_desc[] = {
0x04,       //bLength           4
0x03,       //bDescriptorType       3
0x09, 0x04  //bLanguage             0409 US
};

const uint8_t *str1_desc = 
(uint8_t *)"\x36\x03O\0p\0t\0i\0c\0o\0n\0 \0U\0S\0B\00\0B\0a\0r\0c\0o\0d\0e\0 \0R\0e\0a\0d\0e\0r";
```

The main function is the same as in the example, but the process_urb() function is what has mainly been changed. The control section is largely intact, but I've added handling for some additional setup packets:

```
uint8_t rt = urb->bmRequestType;
uint8_t r = urb->bRequest;
if(rt == 0x00 && r == URB_RQ_SET_CONFIGURATION)
{
    devlog("URB_RQ_SET_CONFIGURATION\n");
    urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
else if(rt == 0x00 && r == URB_RQ_SET_INTERFACE)
{
    devlog("URB_RQ_SET_INTERFACE\n");
    urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
else if (rt == 0x21 && r == 0x20)
{
    devlog("URB_CDC_SET_LINE_CODING\n");
    urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
else if (rt == 0x21 && r == 0x22)
{
    devlog("URB_CDC_SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE\n");
    urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
else if(rt == 0x80 && r == URB_RQ_GET_DESCRIPTOR)
{
    int l = urb->wLength;
    uint8_t *buffer = urb->buffer;
    devlog("GET_DESCRIPTOR ");
    switch(urb->wValue >> 8)
    {
    case 0:
        puts("WTF_DESCRIPTOR");
        urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
        break;
    case 1:
        puts("DEV_DESC");
        if(dev_desc[0] < l) l = dev_desc[0];
        memcpy(buffer, dev_desc, l);
        urb->buffer_actual = l;
        urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
        break;
    case 2:
        puts("CONF_DESC");
        if(conf_desc[2] < l) l = conf_desc[2];
        memcpy(buffer, conf_desc, l);
        urb->buffer_actual = l;
        urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
        break;
    case 3:
        devlog(" Reading string %d\n", urb->wValue & 0xff);
        switch(urb->wValue & 0xff)
        {
        case 0:
            if(str0_desc[0] < l) l = str0_desc[0];
            memcpy(buffer, str0_desc, l);
            urb->buffer_actual = l;
            urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
            break;
        case 1:
            if(str1_desc[0] < l) l = str1_desc[0];
            memcpy(buffer, str1_desc, l);
            urb->buffer_actual = l;
            urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
            break;
        default:
            devlog(" Trying to read unknown string: %d\n",urb->wValue & 0xff);
            urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_STALL;
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        devlog(" UNKNOWN: wValue=%d (%d)\n",urb->wValue, urb->wValue >> 8);
        urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_STALL;
        break;
    }
}
else
{
    devlog("OTHER bmRequestType %x bRequest %x\n", rt, r);
    urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_STALL;
}
```

The main issue is in handling the non-control transfers though. Here's my current implementation:

```
/* handle non-control sequences */
if(!usb_vhci_is_control(urb->type)) {
    /* if we have a BULK OUT transfer */
    if (usb_vhci_is_bulk(urb->type) && usb_vhci_is_out(urb->epadr)) {
        /* we have a bulk out transfer, i.e. a command from client */
        int cmd = get_at_command(urb->buffer, urb->buffer_actual);
        if (cmd == COMMAND_Z1) {
            /* we have request for version, need to wait for the BULK IN transfer */
            last_command = cmd;
        }
        urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
        return;
    }

    /* if we have a BULK IN transfer */
    if (usb_vhci_is_bulk(urb->type) && usb_vhci_is_in(urb->epadr)) {
        /* we have a BULK IN transfer, use it to respond to any buffered commands */
        if (last_command) {
            /* send version */
            memcpy(urb->buffer, VERSION_STR, strlen(VERSION_STR));
            urb->buffer_actual = strlen(VERSION_STR);
            last_command = 0;
            urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
            return;
        }
    }

    urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    return;
}
```

Here's a snippet of the usbmon log I get as my device is starting up:

```
ffff880510727900 266671312 S Bi:5:002:2 -115 128 <
ffff880510727f00 266671315 C Bi:5:002:2 0 0
ffff880510727f00 266671316 S Bi:5:002:2 -115 128 <
ffff880510727cc0 266671319 C Ii:5:002:3 0:8 0
ffff880510727cc0 266671321 S Ii:5:002:3 -115:8 64 <
ffff880514d80900 266671323 S Co:5:002:0 s 21 22 0000 0000 0000 0
ffff880510727780 266671324 C Bi:5:002:2 0 0
ffff880510727780 266671325 S Bi:5:002:2 -115 128 <
ffff8805101096c0 266671329 C Bi:5:002:2 0 0
ffff8805101096c0 266671333 S Bi:5:002:2 -115 128 <
ffff8805107273c0 266671339 C Bi:5:002:2 0 0
ffff8805107273c0 266671344 S Bi:5:002:2 -115 128 <
ffff880510109b40 266671348 C Bi:5:002:2 0 0
ffff880510109b40 266671350 S Bi:5:002:2 -115 128 <
ffff880510109000 266671354 C Bi:5:002:2 0 0
ffff880510109000 266671357 S Bi:5:002:2 -115 128 <
ffff880510727d80 266671360 C Bi:5:002:2 0 0
ffff880510727d80 266671361 S Bi:5:002:2 -115 128 <
ffff880510109a80 266671363 C Bi:5:002:2 0 0
ffff880510109c00 266671370 C Bi:5:002:2 0 0
...
```

So, this is basically where I'm stuck. I've got a nearly functioning device, but the massive amounts of transfers basically chokes my system rendering it useless. Any help or info would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems I have been able to resolve most of my issues now, and the problem was indeed me not responding correctly to events.

After doing some more detailed analysis of the usbmon output for the real device I noticed that it was responding to the superfluous interrupt transfers with -ENOENT, whereas I was responding with 0 (i.e. success). Some more digging into the usb-vhci code revealed that this error code corresponded to USB_VHCI_STATUS_CANCELED, and once I started responding with this I got the same behavior in my device as with the real device. Essentially I added this to my non-control section of process_urb:

```
/* if we have a INTERRUPT transfer */
if (usb_vhci_is_int(urb->type)) {
    urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_CANCELED;
    return;
}
```

I'm not entirely out of the woods yet though. I noticed that the same thing seemed to apply for bulk IN transfers; I'm getting a ton of them during startup (which stop as soon as setup is complete) which - again - does not appear to be the case for the real device, and the real device - again - responds to these (superfluous) transfers with -ENOENT. I tried doing this, and it appears to work fine. The additional transfers do stop and it behaves just as the real device, but unfortunately it also results in my device not being able to send data back to the client. I modified my bulk IN handling code as follows:

```
/* if we have a BULK IN transfer */
if (usb_vhci_is_bulk(urb->type) && usb_vhci_is_in(urb->epadr)) {
    if (last_command) {
        // send version
        memcpy(urb->buffer, VERSION_STR, strlen(VERSION_STR));
        urb->buffer_actual = strlen(VERSION_STR);
        last_command = 0;
        urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        urb->status = USB_VHCI_STATUS_CANCELED;
    }
    return;
}
```

I figure this *should* work, i.e. if I received a command in the previous bulk OUT transfer I should be able to use the IN transfer to respond (as I've been doing all along) and if there was no command I just respond with -ENOENT. For some reason this does not work though and I'm not sure why.

Another thing I noticed regarding the trace from the real device: although it does respond to these bulk transfers with -ENOENT, they send the response more than 10 seconds (!) after they received the request! Not sure what that's all about, but if anyone has an idea I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I just started to work on something similar to this, have to port VHCI code to kernel 4.15 though and handle all USB requests from host and emulate a virtual device in kernel space instead of user space. Were you able to handle all USB requests with libusb_vhci code?  Want to get an idea if my plan is feasible at all.

Comment: @luke: It's been a while since I worked with it, but as far as I can recall I could handle all requests.